# Mongoose to JSON and back to Mongoose Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose document that I generated from a query to MongoDB:

```
const newUser = await User.create(user);
```

,where `User` is the model, and `user` is an object that I am parsing from the body of a POST request.

I am then computing some other fields from other tables which I want to insert inside this `User` document. Rather than doing another database query, I decided to reuse the `newUser` document and convert it to JSON as follows:

```
newUserJSON = newUser.toObject();
```

...this allows me to do stuff like:

```
newUserJSON.parentName = parent[0].name;
```

Now I want to save this updated JSON object into its original Mongoose document format. How can I do this? Also, is this method better than querying and updating the database each time?

Comment: why don't you just use the ``save()`` method? Just add the attributes after the ``create()``, then use ``save()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just overwrite parts of documents that you want to change and use User.save() to save changes on document

Comment: Do you mean, I do not need to convert to JSON? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have no example how your object and schema looks like but you could use something like `parent[0].name = 'newname' ; parent[0].surname = 'newsurname'  parent[0].save()`